# And and Or confusion

Tags: python, operators

I have a file I'm parsing, on each line in the same column are one of the values; 0, 1 or -1. I want to parse this so that the numeric values are all in line as below. I am trying to this via an if statement with and/or operators. I cannot get my head around the and/or as when I test this with a print statement, output either prints 1's or prints 0's.

```
 Desired output:
 0
 1
-1

if number.startswith('1' and '0'):
    return number.append(' ')
print number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'1' and '0'` resolves to just `'0'`:

```
>>> '1' and '0'
'0'
```

Boolean operators are not the same thing English grammatical constructs!

The [`str.startswith()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) takes a tuple of values to test for:

```
number.startswith(('1', '0'))
```

and it'll return `True` if your string starts with `'1'` or it starts with `'0'`.

However, in this case you can just use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) to pad out your number:

```
return format(int(number), '-2d')
```

This pads your number out to a field two characters wide, leaving space for a negative sign:\

```
>>> format(-1, '-2d')
'-1'
>>> format(0, '-2d')
' 0'
>>> format(1, '-2d')
' 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the expression `'1' and '0'` is being evaluated as a `bool`, and will evaluate to `'0'`. The whole expression will then be `if number.startswith('0'):` so the `'1'` is never being checked.

You should to change this

```
if number.startswith('1' and '0'):
```

To

```
if number.startswith('1') or number.startswith('0'):
```

Or

```
if number[0] in ('1', '0'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're using .startswith with a coherent intention, but the arguments don't work that way, try this:

```
if number.startswith('1', '0'):
```

Secondly, .append does not do what you want. If you want to add a space in front of **number** if it begins with '1' or '0', try this:

```
if number.startswith('1', '0'):
    number = ' ' + number
print number
```

Additionally, .append is used to add an item to the end of a list, for example:

```
>>> list = [1, 2]
>>> list.append('x')
>>> list
[1, 2, 'x']
```